# How to save plots by names of items in a list

Tags: r, plot, lapply, glm

I can save a bunch of plots but it names them as the first value from each list item rather than the name of the variable.

```
delm2<-data.frame(N = c(5.881, 5.671, 7.628, 4.643, 6.598, 4.485, 4.465, 4.978, 4.698, 3.685, 4.915, 4.983, 3.288, 5.455, 5.411, 2.585, 4.321, 4.661), 
                  t1 = c("N", "N", "T", "T", "N", "N", "T", "N", "N", "N", "N", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "T", "N"), 
                  t3 = c("r","v", "r", "v", "v", "r", "c", "c", "v", "r", "c", "c", "r", "v","c", "r", "v", "c"), 
                  B = c(1.3, 1.3, 1.33, 1.25, 1.4, 1.34, 1.36, 1.39, 1.36, 1.42, 1.38, 1.31, 1.37, 1.44, 1.22, 1.4, 1.46, 1.35))


library(boot)

lapply(as.list(delm2[,c('N','B')]), 
       function(i){
         bmp(filename = paste0(i,".bmp"), width = 350, height = 400)
         glm.diag.plots(glm(i ~ t1*t3,data=del))
         dev.off()   
       })
```

This saves the plots but they are named with number values from the data rather than the name of each target of `lapply`...
**i.e. current output is two files named "5.881" and "1.3", when I want the same two files but named "N" and "B"**

I thought I could change `paste0(i,".bmp")` to `paste0(names(i),".bmp")` but that just saves the first one, with no name at all.

It looks like you can give names that are just integers in [How to save and name multiple plots with R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27081773/how-to-save-and-name-multiple-plots-with-r) but I want the names of the variables from the list or the two numerics `N` and `B` in delm2.

It looks from [Saving a list of plots by their names()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6701810/saving-a-list-of-plots-by-their-names) like this would be easier with `ggplot` output but `ggsave` didn't work on one `glm.diag.plots` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disregard my previous suggestion using `Map`.)

The big takeaway is how to derive the formula dynamically. One way is with `as.formula`, which takes a string and converts into a formula that can be used in a model-generating function (for example).

One problem with using `lapply(as.list(delm2[,c('N','B')]), ...)` is that the remainder of the data (i.e., columns `t1` and `t3`) are not passed, just one vector at a time. (I'm wondering if your reference to `del` is a typo, un-released/hidden data, or something else.)

Try this:

```r
lapply(c("N", "B"), function(nm) {
  bmp(filename = paste(nm, ".bmp"), width = 350, height = 400)
  glm.diag.plots(glm(as.formula(paste(nm, "~ t1*t3")), data = delm2))
  dev.off()
})
```

In general, I don't like breaching scope inside these functions. That is, I try to not reach outside `lapply` for data when I can pass it fairly easily. The above in a pedantic-language way could look like:

```r
lapply(c("N", "B"), function(nm, x) {
  bmp(filename = paste(nm, ".bmp"), width = 350, height = 400)
  glm.diag.plots(glm(as.formula(paste(nm, "~ t1*t3")), data = x))
  dev.off()
}, x = delm2)
```

While this preserves scope, it may be confusing if you do not understand what is going on.

This might be a great time to use `for` instead of one of the `*apply*` functions. Everything you want is in side-effect, and since `for` and `*apply` are effectively the same speed, you gain readability:

```r
for (nm in c("N", "B")) {
  bmp(filename = paste(nm, ".bmp"), width = 350, height = 400)
  glm.diag.plots(glm(as.formula(paste(nm, "~ t1*t3")), data = delm2))
  dev.off()
}
```

(In this case, there is no "scope breach", so I used the original variable.)

---

**Parenthetically**, to tie-in my now-edited-out and incorrect answer that included `Map`. Here's an example using `Map` that does more to demonstrate what `Map` (and `mapply`) are doing, vice actually improving on your immediate need.

If for some reason you wanted them named something distinct from `"N.bmp"`, you could do this:

```r
Map(function(fn, vn, x) {
  bmp(filename = paste(nm, ".bmp"), width = 350, height = 400)
  glm.diag.plots(glm(as.formula(paste(nm, "~ t1*t3")), data = x))
  dev.off()
}, c("N2.bmp", "b3456.bmp"), c("N", "B"), list(delm2))
```

Two things to note from this:

- The use of `list(delm2)` is to wrap that structure into a single "thing" that is passed repeated to the mapped function. If we did just `delm2` (no `list(...)`), then it would try to use the first column of `delm2` with each of the first elements. This might be useful in other scenarios, but in your `glm` example you need other columns present, so you cannot include just one column at a time. (Well, there are ways to do that, too ... but important at the moment.)
- The first time the anonymous function is called, `fn` is `"N2.bmp"`, vn`is`"N"`, and`x`is the full dataset of`delm2`. The second time the anon-func is called,`fn`is`"b3456.bmp"`,`vn`is`"B"`, and`x`is again the full dataset of`delm2`.

I label this portion "parenthetic" because it really doesn't add to *this* problem, but since I started that way in my first-cut answer, I thought I'd continue with the methodology, the "why" of my choice of `Map`. In the end, I think the `for` solution or one of the `lapply` solutions should be fine for you.

Comment: Okay, see my even-more-recent edit, as I mis-read some of the question initially.